# Как совместить два значения в одном textBox в формате IP/MASK?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как совместить значения, чтобы можно было ввести IP адрес и маску, например: `192.168.0.0/24`

На данный момент используется два `textBox` и это не удобно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void WriteRegKey(string keyName, string ip1, string ipm1)
{
    string input1 = ip1; // IP адрес из textBox1
    string hexIP = string.Concat(input1.Split('.')
                         .Select(x => int.Parse(x)
                         .ToString("X2")
                         .PadLeft(2, '0')));

    int cidr1 = int.Parse(ipm1); // Маска подсети из textbox1
    BitVector32 bits1 = new BitVector32(-1 << (32 - cidr1));
    string hexMASK = bits1.Data.ToString("X2");
}

private void buttonHex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteRegKey("ipsecData", textBoxIP1.Text, textBoxIPm1.Text)
}
```

Нужно, чтобы IP и маска подсети была в одном `textBox` как показано ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создать массив с 2 элементами и при чтении из textbox использовать **/**, как разделитель - записать всё, что идёт до **/** в первый элемент массива, а всё, что после - во второй элемент.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924000/ip-address-in-a-maskedtextbox

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам ссылка из моего комментария не помогла, то добавлю подробностей ответом.

Для контролируемого ввода Ip адреса следует использовать не `TextBox`, а стандартный элемент `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox`, который есть в панели инструментов редактора форм. Соответственно маска должна иметь вид

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "###\\.###\\.#\\.#\\/##";
```

В результате Вы будете использовать единственный элемент ввода, который будет иметь желаемый для Вас вид.

P.S.: Добавлю полезные ссылки https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.4.php о том как формировать шаблон и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924000/ip-address-in-a-maskedtextbox - как обработать, то что получили.

Comment: +1 направление правильное. Только подойдет ли маска для произвольного IP? Например, для 192.168.102.0. Насколько я понял после быстрого поиска, адекватный ввод IP — дело неблагодарное ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924000/ip-address-in-a-maskedtextbox), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884857/need-a-net-winforms-ip-address-control))

Comment: @default locale первая ссылка - это ссылка из моего комментария :). Теперь, что касается Вашего вопроса - по поводу произвольного IP - нет конечно, но автор вопроса просил решить проблему для этого частного случая. Вы совершенно верно отметили, что "адекватный ввод IP — дело неблагодарное". Прежде чем комментировать вопрос я тоже сделал поиск. Подождем реакции автора - важно с чего-то начать.

Comment: Точки тоже нужно экранировать: `\\.`, т. к. они имеют свое значение в маске.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov спасибо :) моя невнимательность, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Даже если получить значение по маске `192.168.0.0/24` все равно придется разделить его на переменные `ip1` и `ipm1`

Comment: @Vitokhv, да безусловно придется рассматривать части по разные стороны /  раздельно. Но Вы просили в своем вопросе сделать так, чтобы был только один элемент редактирования :). Еще пара замечаний - в моей строке шаблон символ '#' лучше заменить '9' . Так Вы сможете кроме цифр вводить пробел и получите больше возможностей для ввода. Соответственно, конвертировать строку в IP нужно методом по ссылке из моего комментария к вопросу. Я сейчас в метро - завтра я подкорректирую вопрос.